# declaring output schema when using gapply in Sparkr

Tags: dataframe, schema, sparkr, gapply

I would like to use `gapply` according to https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html#gapply

The problem is I am returning a list of 2 dataframes.

return(list(df1, df2))

How do I declare the output schema in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use function returning arbitrary list. [As per `gapply` documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/gapply.html) (emphasis mine):

> The function func takes as argument a key - grouping columns and a data frame - a local R `data.frame`. **The output of func is a local `R data.frame`**.

You might be make it work by treating each `data.frame` as a single `Row` of type equivalent to something `struct<col1:array<typeofcol1>, col2:array<typeofcol2>, ..., coln:array<typeofcoln>>`, **but only** as long as both output `data.frames` have identical schema.